# Target all inputs in multiple forms with the same class

Tags: jquery

I have several forms in my page - all with the same class. Each of these forms has an hidden element called ProductId. I'm trying to update this input in all of the forms that match the class but get unrecognized expression error:

```
$('.PoForm input["ProductId"]').val(parentPK);
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `ProductId` ... Is it a `class` , `id` or any other attribute ? . It will help if you can paste your `HTML` of the input in question

Comment: no it's the name of the hidden element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.ProductId` to match the product id. `[]` is used for attribute

```
$('.PoForm input.ProductId').val(parentPK);
```

if this is the only element with the class `productID` inside the form then just do:

```
$('.PoForm .ProductId').val(parentPK);
```

if it is name then:

```
$('.PoForm input[name=ProductId]').val(parentPK);
```

if it is `id` then id must be unique so change it to `name` or `class`.

Comment: Thanks so much this was the most thorough answer! - I used the last option because it targets the forms as well.

Comment: @JulianDormon You are welcome, was unsure what is ProductID so tried to include all options that i can think of.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want this to select multiple classes of ProductId.

```
$('.ProductId').val(parentPK);
```

or this to get all input with the name ProductId.

```
$('input[name=ProductId]').val(parentPK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do....

```
$('input[name=ProductId]').val(parentPK);
```